# UISwitch resets TextField value after on/off

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiswitch

I created

```
- (IBAction)passwordSwitchPressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.passwordSwitch.isOn) {
        self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;

    }
    else {
        self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = NO;
    }
}
```

And condition is that if switch is On password text field secure entry is on, else off. Everything works perfect, but if I change from on to off, and then go back to on, value in password text field dissapear. How to solve this?

Comment: please provide more code.

Comment: Hi, I've added full code for IBAction...

Comment: there must be another reason somewhere else - maybe in a delegate method which is called after a change. The `passwordSwitchPressed` method works as expected.

Comment: Hmmm, I will check, but I think it's system option for iOS, and maybe there is some method that are keeping entry from text field on change of switch state...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After setting the delegate to the textfield. Try the below way. Hope it will work.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *oldString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    textField.text = oldString;

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping reference to the input, let me know :)

```
- (IBAction)passwordSwitchPressed:(id)sender 
{
    NSString * passValue = self.passwordTextField.text;

    self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = self.passwordSwitch.isOn;
    self.passwordTextField.text = passValue;
}
```

Comment: So your problem lies elsewhere, like varian just mentioned. There must be another function that resets your input..

Comment: I will try this case in empty app, where I will have one text field and switch and nothing else, I will let you know if this problem shows there.